# Why don't we use diffusion for non-graph CNNs?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks

I'm pretty new to graph neural networks, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

Diffusion is a method used to improve graph CNNs, however it seems to me that general CNNs can also benefit from taking into consideration diffusion-like processes (for example, in CV, one may want information to diffuse from a small neighborhood, then to a bigger neighborhood, etc.). Also, PDE-based methods have been used in CV traditionally (before deep learning became a thing), so there's at least some evidence that this might work. But I did search extensively, and I can't find any information on using diffusion for general CNNs!

Therefore, what I'm curious about is: why didn't I find any information about this? Is it already explored under a different name? Or does it not really work because of some reason I don't know (or didn't think about)? Or maybe it does work, but there are some technical difficulties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, here is one simple formalization of a diffusion GCN ([Gasteiger et al.](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/23c894276a2c5a16470e6a31f4618d73-Paper.pdf)):

$\text{D-GCN}(X) = \sum_{k=1}^K A^k X W_k$

You have a diffusion factor $k \in [1 .. K]$ and you apply different GCNs with parameters $W_k$ to the $1$-hop, $2$-hop, .., $K$-hop neighborhood and sum the results together. $A^k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ power of the adjacency matrix.

There are two principles in visual CNNs that come to my mind that are comparable to the diffusion applied in graph models.

Firstly, [**dilated convolutions**](https://iq.opengenus.org/dilated-convolution/) apply a kind of diffusion (they are also referred to as Atrous convolution). Specifically, the convolutional kernel is spread out based on a dilation factor $d$. The dilation factor determines the number of pixels that are skipped when applying the kernel. For example, if you have a 3x3 kernel, and apply a dilation rate of $d=1$, you get the standard convolution, a dilation rate of $d=2$ applies the 3x3 kernel to a 5x5 area of the image by using only every 2nd pixel (see the Image below). So in that case $d$ determines which pixel neighborhood the kernel is applied to, which is comparable to the $k$ in the diffusion GCN.
Dilated convolution has a history in segmentation models (see [Yu et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07122) and [Chen et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00915)). Apparently, it helps with segmentation, because the dilated convolutions can capture the context of pixels a bit better, so segmentation maps become cleaner.
It has also been applied with 1-dimensional convolutions in the [WaveNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03499) architecture. In that case dilation was used to cover greater receptive fields without increasing the number of parameters, i.e. model complexity.

[image]

*The green is the output, blue is the input and the grayed pixels are the pixels where kernel weights are applied to. Image taken from [here](https://iq.opengenus.org/dilated-convolution/)*

Second, the **Inception architecture** by [Szegedy et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842) applies something that can be interpreted as a diffusion as well: Inception computes convolutions of different kernel sizes in parallel and stacks their feature maps ([this blog post](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/inception-module) has a nice visualization). Here, the different kernel sizes would correspond to the $k$ and stacking is used instead of a sum.

I think these two examples are definitely related to the idea of diffusion GCN.